# data does not appear in the ui grid

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ui-grid

I'm trying to populate Angularjs UI grid, when  geocoder.geocode of google map executes, the UI grid populated..but nothing its appears ine the navigator until i click something on the DOM then the data appears in the UI grid..why it behaves like that???

```
 geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
              //console.log("vb");
              $scope.cp++;

            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[1]) {
                console.log('azerty: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.aqw[index]) );
                $scope.aqw[index].adress=results[1].formatted_address;
                if($scope.cp == $scope.Mylength){
                 //alert(JSON.stringify($scope.aqw));
                 $scope.gridOptions.data=$scope.aqw;
              }
                map.setZoom(11);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng,
                  map: map
                });
                //console.log("vbbbb");
                $scope.varr=results[1].formatted_address;
                infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                //alert("kl");
              } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
            $scope.titi="djdjd";
           // console.log( $scope.varr+'   '+'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc');
            console.log('azertym: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.aqw[index]) );
            $scope.myData={};
            $scope.myData+=$scope.aqw[index];
            console.log('yoyoyoyo: ' +   JSON.stringify($scope.aqw));

          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming it is because of the `digest cycle`, the scope isn't aware of the changes and there for it is not updating the dom.

you can include a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the callback function. and this will fix the issue...

read more about digest and apply here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: where i put it ??

Comment: at the end of the callback

Comment: right after `console.log('yoyoyoyo: ' +   JSON.stringify($scope.aqw));`

Comment: great please note that you cant run `$scope.$apply` whenever :P only one digest cycle can be running at a time... Good luck

Comment: i didnt understant..you mean i have to use it once??

Comment: only 1 digest cycle can be running at a time that means that if you run $scope.$apply while the digest cycle is running it will through an error so only use it in callbacks like this one, where angular isnt aware of the change

Comment: dont worry about it :) you will get it when it happens

Comment: @abdellatifzoumhane happy to help!